# Making reusable component for array data in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I want to make a footer component in react with a heading and several links under it like in the image.
[image: Footer]

Also I want to pass only an array for the links like the following.

```
const FooterLinksData = [
    {
        link1: "Insolvers",
        link2: "How it works?",
        link3: "I'm looking for job",
        link4: "I'm looking to hire",
    },
    {
        link1: "Features",
        link2: "Pricing",
        link3: "Schedule a Demo",
    },
];
```

My code:

```
  return (
        <>
            <li>
                <a href="/" className="footer_link">
                    {props.data[`link${props.num + 1}`]}
                </a>
            </li>
            // I have written this li tag for times in my code
            // props.data is the array I passed using the parent
            // props.num is the number (0 in this case) to get link1 from 
            // the object
        </>
    );
```

My problem is that first obj under the array has 4 items while the second one only have 3. Is there any way to make a reusable component for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
You can add the title inside the json and use it to bracke. Something like


    const FooterLinksData = [
       {
          "title":"some title",
          "links":[
             "Insolvers",
             "How it works"
          ]
       },
       {
          "title":"some other title",
          "links":[
             "other Insolvers",
             "other How it works"
          }]
    ];

so then you will do something like:

FooterLinksData.map(({title, links}) => ({
    <div>
       <div>{title}</div>
       <ul>{links.map(link => <li>{link}</li>)}</ul>
    </div>
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ask this question, I assume you use `FooterLinksData[x].link1, FooterLinksData[x].link2, FooterLinksData[x].link3 .....` to display your links.

You could change your code to use the [map() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead, not having to deal with a fixed number of links.

Can't really help with code since you didn't posted how you render your links.